# How can I recreate piechart (AChartEngine) on spinner item click in Android?

Tags: android, achartengine, pie-chart

Am using **AChartEngine** library to displaying data's in `PieChart` view in my project. Initially I created **Dataset**, **Render**, **View** and **Chart Factory** to create PieChart and its working fine. For eg *PieChart for Gender*

```
OnCreate(){
   malecount = 3; 
   femalecount = 1;

    createpiechart(); // Creating PieChart initially
}
```

This code is working fine. PieChart with male & Female with 2 different colors that mentioned as static.
 Now I add `Spinner` for filters, add event for that Spinner `OnItemSelectedListener`.

```
String selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
if(selectedItem.equals("Last Week"))
{
    malecount = 2; femalecount = 1;  // clear existing values from temp memory and add new values
    mSeries.clear(); // clear the dataset

    createpiechart(); // recreate piechart
}
```

in that create **piechart method** again execute the same code as before.

```
private void createpiechart() {

    VALUES = new int[] { malecount, femalecount };
    mRenderer.setChartTitle("Gender");
    mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    mRenderer.setLabelsColor(0xff000000); // Black color
    mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
    mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 20, 30, 15, 0 });
    mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    mRenderer.setStartAngle(90);


    for (int i = 0; i < VALUES.length; i++) {

        mSeries.add(NAME_LIST[i] + " " + VALUES[i], VALUES[i]);
        SimpleSeriesRenderer renderer = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setColor(COLORS[(mSeries.getItemCount() - 1)
                                 % COLORS.length]);
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
    }

    if (mChartView != null) {
        mChartView.repaint();
    }

    if (mChartView == null) {
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
        mChartView = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(this, mSeries, mRenderer);
        mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
        mRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(10);

        mChartView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // nothing
            }
        });
        layout.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    }
    else {
        mChartView.repaint();
    }
}
```

After executing the same code **Green and Blue color** of Male & Female in Bottom changes to **white color**, I need same color before it shown. Check this image below and help me how to change that color back or whats wrong with this code ?

[image]

Comment: Hello PieChart is Recreatedd u r Not Chaning or PieChart

Comment: Chnage value of Pai Chart when u want to recreate chart

Comment: Sorry am new to AChartEngine, Can you tell How to change the value ?

Comment: where is NAME_LIST[i] array

Comment: NAME_LIST[I] this array is constant only (Male & Female)

Comment: 1st initially my piechart is created using values male=3, female=1 and now if spinner is selected 'Last Week' I need ti set different values like male=2, female=1 now how to clear all values from piechart and add new piechart ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60441/discussion-between-sri-and-naveen-tamrakar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just clear Dataset and Renderer and then pass new values.

To clear dataset

```
int size = dataset.getSeriesCount();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
dataset.removeSeries(0);
}
```

To clear Renderer `renderer.removeAllRenderers();`